# How to show section title before section number

Tags: sectioning, formatting

The default style is section number and then section title, however I want it the other way around. Haven't been able to find a solution that doesn't give me strange errors, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1\ \thesection}

\begin{document}

\section{A Test Section} 
\section{Another Test Section} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Similar redefinitions can be done for the other sectional units, if required.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you all so much :)

Comment: Omitting a section from numbering with * doesn't work using this method, is there an alternative to achieve this?

Comment: @JordanMackie, a quick workaround is to use Gonzalo's hack for ``subsubsection`` instead, while keeping ``section`` unchanged (assuming you don't otherwise use subsubsection). In the above, ``\section`` becomes ``\subsubsection`` and ``\thesection`` becomes ``\thesubsubsection``.

Answer (score 8):

In ConTeXt you can use

```
\setuphead[alternative=command, command=\swap]
\unexpanded\def\swap#1#2{#2\space#1}

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=5mm]
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: After seeing some of the answers that you have given using ConTeXt which I've also answered but using LaTeX, I am increasingly tempted to start studying ConTeXt seriously.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example (MWE) for the standard `report`-class. The code is copied from [Vincent Zoonekynd](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) and modified. The code for the `book`-class will be little different:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1 \quad
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \Huge\bfseries
      \thechapter
      \par\nobreak
    \fi
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Test}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

And if you use `article`-class and only needs `\section`, here more code from the same source, slightly modified to suit your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\section{\@ifstar\unnumberedsection\numberedsection}
\def\numberedsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \numberedsectionwithtwoarguments\numberedsectionwithoneargument}
\def\unnumberedsection{\@ifnextchar[%]
  \unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments\unnumberedsectionwithoneargument}
\def\numberedsectionwithoneargument#1{\numberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\unnumberedsectionwithoneargument#1{\unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]{#1}}
\def\numberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
  \ifhmode\par\fi
  \removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
  \refstepcounter{section}%
  \hbox to \hsize{%
    \vtop{\parindent=0pt \leavevmode\Large\bfseries\raggedright #2\quad\thesection\par}%
    }
  \vskip 2ex\nobreak\noindent%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thesection}%
    #1}%
  \ignorespaces}
\def\unnumberedsectionwithtwoarguments[#1]#2{%
  \ifhmode\par\fi
  \removelastskip
  \vskip 3ex\goodbreak
  \hbox to \hsize{%
    \vtop{\parindent=0pt\leavevmode\Large\bfseries\raggedright #2\par}%
    }
  \vskip 2ex\nobreak\noindent%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
    #1}%
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section*{Introduction}
\lipsum[3-4]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{document}
```

In any case, it demonstrates clearly how much simpler life is due to `titlesec` and `secstyle`.

Comment: The question was about sections.

Comment: Code for `\section` is added. Much more work than I anticipated. Use of `secsty` or `titlesec`is recommended. (Or use `KOMA-script` or `memoir`.)