# How to cross reference to multiple appendices in an article?

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

Kindly help me. I have three appendixes in my research article. I want to cross-ref in my document. However, I am not able to do so. I am sorry that i could not post the question with clarity. Thus, i am posting once again the minimum working file which i hope is sufficient. It would be better if you can help me in cross-referring to three appendices: Appendix I, Appendix II, and Appendix III. (Kindly note that i want appendix to be named liked this)

So, the minimum working file is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,dvips,top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,foot=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents %run twice to get the table of contents.
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
XYZ.........ABC
\section{Lit Review}
XYZ.........ABC
\section{Data}

See Appendix \ref{app:1} for results of unit root test. For detailed discussion of construction of variable, see Appendix \ref{app:2}. See Figure 1 in the Appendix \ref{app:3}.

\section{Results and Interpretation}

\newpage
\appendix
\addappheadtotoc
\begin{subappendices}
\begin{center}
\section*{Appendix I} \label{app:1}
\end{center}
ABCDEF........XYZ

\begin{center}
\section*{Appendix II} \label{app:2}
\end{center}

This Appendix is intended to describe the sources of data and construction of indices and variables used in the econometric analysis.

\begin{center}
\section*{Appendix III} \label{app:3}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Net Procurement and Foodgrains Inflation}
        \includegraphics[width=12cm, height=8cm]{np_graph.eps}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

=====================
When i run  this code, i am able to cross-ref to respective appendices. The problem is that in the text the appendix numbers are coming wrong. For example, if i want to show See Appendix I for results of unit root test, the final output is showing "See Appendix '8' for results of unit root test." Why 8, i don't know.
Kindly help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` ... not `\begin{document}` twice.

Comment: Assuming `subappendices` I would assume also that `\subsection` is the relevant structure level there (since `article` or something similar) seems to be the class. As such, `\subsection` provides the correct counter stepping and a `\label` will work. Of course, `\textbf{Appendix II}` does not provide the correct information for `\label`

Comment: Your 'MWE' is not compilable and of course the cross - reference is wrong since there's no `\refstepcounter` command in `\section*` providing the correct label! Also: Why `subappendices` when using `\section`?

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Instead of putting the (mostly redundant) word "Appendix" in the section-level headers in the appendix, use descriptive labels for these headers. After all, you don't put "Section" in the section-level headers in the main body of the document, do you?
- Use `\section` rather than `\section*` to generate numbered (or lettered) section-level headers in the appendix.
- If you need to center-set section-level headers, load the `sectsty` package and issue the directive `\sectionfont{\centering}` at the start of the appendix material.
- Last but not least, consider loading the `cleveref` package and using `\cref` to generate cross-references. A nice feature of `\cref` is that it can contain multiple objects in its argument. (For more information on various LaTeX cross-referencing packages, see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,sectsty,appendix}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\title{Title}
\author{Author(s)}
\date{Date}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures

%%%\listoftables

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
XYZ\dots ABC

\section{Lit Review}
XYZ\dots ABC
\section{Data}

See \cref{app:1} for results of unit root tests. For a detailed 
discussion of construction of variable, see \cref{app:2,app:3}. 
And, see \cref{fig:1} in \cref{app:3}.

\section{Results and Interpretation}

\newpage
%% center-set the section-level headers
\sectionfont{\centering}
\appendix
\addappheadtotoc
%%%\begin{subappendices}

\section{Appendix about stuff} \label{app:1}

ABCDEF\dots XYZ

\section{Appendix about more stuff} \label{app:2}

This Appendix is intended to describe the sources of data and 
construction of indices and variables used in the econometric analysis.

\section{Appendix about still more stuff} \label{app:3}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Net Procurement and Foodgrains Inflation}
    \label{fig:1}
    \includegraphics[width=12cm, height=8cm]{np_graph.eps}
\end{figure}

%%%\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico, it would be great if you can tweak the command so that i can get Appendix I, Appendix II and so on instead of Appendix A, Appendix B as you have written? And Appendix I should be centered.  Thank you a lot.

Comment: @santosh - Just add the instruction `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}` immediately after `\appendix`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a simple redefinition of the sectional numbering format (using `\Roman{section}`) as well as [swapping the sectional number and title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58295/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldappendices\appendices
\renewcommand{\appendices}{%
  \oldappendices
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58295/5764
  \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{##1\ \thesection}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
See Appendix~\ref{app:first-appendix}.

\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendix}\label{app:first-appendix}
An appendix.

\section{Appendix}
Another appendix.

\section{Appendix}
A final appendix.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Werner for your help. However, how to create appendix name "Appendix I" instead of "A Appendices" as you have created. I have provided minimum working file. Sorry, that i could not post the question with more clarity. Kindly see if you can help me. Thank you again.

Comment: @santosh: See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Fixed :) I was trying to fix it for many days. i read this forum but could not help much. Finally, i decided to post it. I could have have done it much before. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @santosh: If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)